Windows 10/11 network does not show all the computers
Three PC - Win 11 Home, Win 10 Pro (2x)

Gigabit Ethernet, router (CISCO/TP-Link/Mikrotik) as DNS and DHCP server (static/dynamic/predetermined), the same workgroup

Setting is the same in all the PCs:
Network = Private network.

Private networks - Network discovery ON, File and printer sharing ON
Public networks - OFF, OFF
All networks - Public folder sharing ON, File sharing 40- or 50/bit, Password protected sharing OFF

After I switch all the computers on, I can seldom see all the three on all the three PCs.
I tried dozens of setting both on PCs and routers. Nothing helps. Restarting router, restarting PCs, DNS flush, ... Every time the visibility is different and after several hours of computing it changes... visible to unvisible, unvisible to visible, some remain the same.
NMAP and AIP scanner checks show everything correctly incl. shares, open ports, etc. Both the apps. run on all the three PCs with the very same result.
I am simply getting mad of it... Any advice or practical experience would be appreciated very much.
